# Regex with grouping groups matches unintuitively?

Tags: java, regex

I am a beginner trying to learn how to use regular expressions in Java. By going through a few online tutorials, I wrote the following sample codes to teach myself how regex with grouping operates, but the results are somewhat unintuitive.

```
String pattern = "((frok |dork )*)(\\w+) is (\\d+) Foo";
System.out.println(test1.matches(pattern));
System.out.println(test1.replaceAll(pattern, "$1"));        
System.out.println(test1.replaceAll(pattern, "$3"));
```

With `test1 = frok dork dumb is 10 Foo`, I get `$1` as `frok dork`, `$3` as `dumb`, as expected.

However, with `test1 = frok dork is 10 Foo`, I expected the match to fail. Instead, I get `$1` as `frok` and `$3` as `dork`. Why does the `dork` match with `\\w+` here instead of `((frok | dork )*)` as in earlier case?

I did search here on SO, but these posts ([Java regular expression with groups](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7188791/252576), [Regular expressions, groups issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10984835/252576), [Is there a way to use a list of string parameters with a regular expression (with groups) to construct a new string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1814036/252576), [Regular expression with variable number of groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5018487/252576)) do not address this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, with `test1 = frok dork is 10 Foo`, I expected the match to fail. Instead, I get `$1` as `frok` and `$3` as `dork`. Why does the `dork` match with `\\w+` here instead of `((frok | dork )*)` as in earlier case?

Your first sentence here is the answer to your question. `((frok |dork )*)` *wants* to match as many occurrences of `frok`  or `dork`  as it can; but the overriding consideration is, it wants the regex match to succeed. If a given part of the regex has to match a little bit less in order to get the match as a whole to succeed, then so be it.

For more information, I suggest Googling for *regex* + *backtracking*, *greedy*, and *nongreedy*.

Comment: I don't think greediness is really relevant here. The results should be the same whether the first group is greedy or not.

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to *prevent* the overriding consideration? I want the match to fail if it is NOT of the form "<one or more keywords> <one non-keyword> is <number> Foo", since I am using this for input validation. The "non-keyword" may not be previously seen, so I cannot explicitly look to match those, and hence have to use `\\w+`.

Comment: @shmosel: Right; that's why I classified it as "more information". Understanding greedy and nongreedy quantifiers deepens one's understanding of the principles at work here, and learning about them is the obvious next step.

Comment: @Happy: Yes; Java regexes support a notion of *possessive quantifiers* which, once they match, will never give back just part of what they matched. That's expressed with an extra `+`: `?` becomes `?+`, `*` becomes `*+`, `+` becomes `++`. So in your case, you would write `String pattern = "((frok |dork )*+)(\\w+) is (\\d+) Foo";`

Comment: @Happy: By the way, I notice that in some of your comments to other answers, you seem to be describing `*` as "nongreedy". That is incorrect. "Greedy" refers to the fact that `*` wants to match as many repetitions as it can (even though it's willing to give some up if necessary); the "nongreedy" counterpart is `*?`, which wants to match as *few* repetitions as it can (though it's willing to match a bit if necessary).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I will read more about it as you suggest and improve my understanding.

Answer (score 3):

**A picture is worth a thousand words!**

So here are your groups—explaining which part of the regex matches what.

[image: RegexBuddy Grops]

**You need a regex debugger**

The best way to see how things match or fail is to use a regex debugger. I work in regex **all the time**, and I wouldn't do it without debugging tools.

On Windows, the Rolls of regex debuggers is RegexBuddy. It is developed by Jan Goyvaerts, the author of *The Regex Cookbook* and of several regex-based tools. Online, regex101 is quite good.

- On the right pane of this [regex 101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/dB6vO1), you can see the groups for each match.
- RegexBuddy has a [free trial](http://yu8.us/rbdemo)

Comment: FYI added a gorgeous screenshot. :)

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of these tools. :) Is there a way to force a  "greedy" matching in the first group? I am using this for input validation, where input is expected to be of type: "<one or more keywords> <one non-keyword> is <number> Foo". I want the match to fail if it is of the type, "<one or more keywords> is <number> Foo", that is, with the <one non-keyword> missing. The non-keyword may not be previously seen, so I cannot explicitly look for a set of non-keywords.

Comment: Hi, glad to hear the answer helps. Sorry for the delay. I am not understanding your follow-up questions, I need examples. :)

Answer (score 1):

`((frok |dork )*)(\\w+)` means there can be *any number* of `frok`s or `dork`s followed by a single word. In the first test, `frok` and `dork` both matched the first group, and `dumb` matched the next. But in your second test, `dork` had to be counted as the single following word in order to match the pattern. Therefore, only `frok` could be counted in the initial group.

Answer (score 1):

There are marking groups `(`*expression*`)` and there are non marking groups `(?:`*expression*`)`. You see the difference. A non marking group has `?:` after opening parenthesis.

The string found by the expression of a marking group can be backreferenced with `$1`, `$2`, ... or `\1`, `\2`, ....

The OR expression in your example should be a non marking group as the inner parentheses are just for the OR expression which should be applied 0 or more times.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. From the tutorials, I couldn't fully understand what ?: was used for, but your answer makes it clear. Is there a way to force "greedy" matching in the first group? I want the regex match to fail if the first group of "keywords" is NOT followed by a "non-keyword".

Comment: `"((?:frok |dork )*)(\\w+)(?<!frok|dork) is (\\d+) Foo"` can be used to find `frok` or `dork` 0 or more times and additionally require one more word before `is` which is whether `frok` nor `dork`. The expression `(?<!frok|dork)` is a negative lookbehind which checks if the string found by `\w+` is whether `frok` nor `dork`.

Answer (score 0):

You have nested groups in the regex: `((frok |dork )*)` so `frok` is captured twice. Then, as you have guessed, `dork` is captured by the `(\\w+)`